# Copy the files if exist else skip in bash

Tags: bash, loops, unix

I want to first check if file on my source location falls within a date range: if yes then copy else skip and check the next file.
Can someone help how this can be done as I am new to shell script.

Comment: I don't understand your script. What are the -newrmt parameters to find ? Is the date part of the filename or do you search for the last modification date?

Comment: @Derlin, it's a GNU extension; check the man page for `-newerXY`.

Comment: Note that `find` won't find files that don't exist.  You can exclude directories (etc) by adding `-type f` so that only files are found.  Your notation with the quote is incorrect.  Using the `for` notation works only if the file names do not contain spaces (or tabs or newlines).  Remember to quote uses of variables; remember to prefix the date variables with a `$`.  Generally, you get the best responses if your code works a bit — yours does not run (invalid syntax).

Comment: BTW, in shell, "clarity" generally needs to come second to correctness: What looks simplest to the reader is very often buggy (albeit frequently in ways that will escape simple testing but then show up later); avoiding hidden pitfalls in the language tends to require knowing and using a body of idiom existing for the purpose.

Comment: You can use `find` to find files within a date range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` already will return only entries that already exist; there's no issue there, but the code you're using to iterate over its results is badly broken.

---

The problem here isn't with skipping, but with correct syntax in general, and (secondarily) with correctness-related practices. Even if you fixed the most immediate bug in the original code, you would have fallen afoul of [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls), and [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

See [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for a full discussion of best practices around using `find`. That said, among the correct approaches are:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^- important: not /bin/sh

while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  mv "$filename" /to_path
done < <(find filedirectory_path/ -type f -newermt "$date1" ! -newermt "$date2" -print0)
```

...or...

```
find filedirectory_path/ -type f -newermt "$date1" ! -newermt "$date2" -exec mv '{}' /to_path \;
```

Comment: Thanks but the piece of code that i shared is just to give a picture of what i need to do. I am pretty bad at scripting :)

Comment: @Ray: don't show us 'a picture of what I need to do'.  Show code that seriously attempts to do what you need to do.  If you're going to put us to the effort of answering your question, at least make the effort yourself to present decent code.  It's really rude to do otherwise.

Comment: I didn't intend to be rude.I guess im too bad at shell scripting to even write a syntactically correct code :(

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, heh. I completely read it that way, to the point of pointing Derlin to `-newerXY` in the man page, but you're right.

Comment: @Ray, ...as I'd describe the issue, the problem is that the code is so wrong that it **doesn't even clearly convey your intent**. We aren't mind readers; we don't know what was in your head when you wrote something. We *are* bash experts, so we know exactly how the shell would interpret that thing, but we don't know how you expect *us* to interpret it.

Comment: @Ray, ...anyhow, why don't you follow the links I gave in my answer, and use them to improve the question? Normally, we frown on questions being edited in a way that makes already-existing answers off-point (the Right Thing is to ask another, better question) -- but you have my blessing this time.

Comment: Thanks alot Everyone :)